# Authentication error with Spring Boot on office365 smtp

Tags: java, spring-boot, email, microsoft365

The authentication method we always used for office365 smtp stoped working and we have no idea why. It always worked normally, the login and password works direct in browser, so this is not the problem.

`spring.mail.properties.mail.transport.protocol=smtp`

`spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.port=587`

`spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.auth=true`

`spring.mail.properties.mail.smtp.starttls.enable=true`

We have this in properties file, I heard that microsoft changed something in email authentication, but cant find what I have to do to make the program authenticate again.